# How to derive the type for `liftM2 fmap zip . mapM`?

Tags: haskell, types, pointfree

I recently had the need for the following function. The idea is to zip up the original `xs` values along with the `mapM f xs` values.

```
zipMapM f xs = fmap (zip xs) (mapM f xs)
```

Putting it through pointfree, I got what, or me, seems like an incomprehensible yet simple result:

```
zipMapM = liftM2 fmap zip . mapM
```

So I tried to figure it out:

```
liftM2 :: Monad m   => (a1 -> a2 -> r) -> m a1 -> m a2 -> m r
fmap   :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
zip    ::              [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]
mapM   :: Monad m   => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]
```

Starting here:

```
liftM2 :: Monad m => (a1 -> a2 -> r) -> m a1 -> m a2 -> m r
liftM2 fmap :: (Monad m, Functor f) => m (a -> b) -> m (f a) -> m (f b)
```

Okay so far. The next step stumped me:

```
liftM2 fmap zip :: Functor f => ([a] -> f [b]) -> [a] -> f [(a, b)]
```

How does one derive this? And then further on towards the final function?

Comment: Also, any chance this is in the standard library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`liftM2` is doing most of the magic. In the "function Monad", `((->) a)`, `liftM2` looks like this

```
liftM2 h f g x = h (f x) (g x)
```

We can use it to immediately eliminate the `xs`

```
zipMapM f xs = fmap (zip xs) (mapM f xs)
zipMapM f xs = liftM2 fmap zip (mapM f) xs
zipMapM f    = liftM2 fmap zip (mapM f)
```

and then if we think of `liftM2 fmap zip` as a function all on it's own, this is exactly the definition of `(.)`

```
(g . f) x = g (f x) -- gives us

zipMapM f    = (liftM2 fmap zip . mapM) f
```

which we can eta reduce

```
zipMapM = liftM2 fmap zip . mapM
```

Comment: Thanks. How do you derive `liftM2 h f g x = h (f x) (g x)` for functions?

Comment: @Opa: Conveniently, there’s only one total implementation. `liftM2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> m a -> m b -> m c`; setting `m = (r ->)` we get `(a -> b -> c) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b) -> r -> c`. You only have one `r`, so you have to spread it to the two unary functions; then you only have one `a` and one `b`, so you have to use the binary function to get a `c`.